# SciPy interpolation error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to interpolate some data (which is ~quadratic), but I get some strange results (very small numerical differences which are periodic). To illustrate that, I've taken the derivative of the interpolated data, where you can see periodic peeks, that indicate there's some discontinuity in the data. I know it is small, but in my case it is important. So when you look the interpolated function over original one looks nice, but when I do some calculus later, I find some strange results which are due to that.

Thanks!!

Picture: http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9444/resultskx.png

Comment: Could you come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this?

Comment: @NPE, This is such an important point. I think it should be in big bright letters on the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page. I often find that between the time of me opening a new question and submitting it, I solve the problem just by needing to describe it clearly, invariably part of which is creating an SSCCE (new acronym for me :). I feel the skill of asking good questions is a very important skill to develop.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are using the correct order fox `x` values, for instance (linear interpolation):

```
def interp_normalize(x, y):
   dorder = {}
   for i, e in enumerate(x):
       dorder[e] = y[i]
   dorder = OrderedDict(sorted(dorder.items()))
   interpolate_x = list(dorder.keys())
   interpolate_y = list(dorder.values())
   return(interpolate_x, interpolate_y)
```